# Use data-attribute for toggle link

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'm very new to jquery. How can I use a `data` attribute for toggling?

I want to select the element with the `class="filter-group"` and the same `data-toggle` attribute like the button has:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var toggleID = $(this).data('toggle');
  $('.filter-group[data-toggle= toggleID ]').toggle();
});
```

https://codepen.io/elkeschiffer/pen/PWZKmE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
$('.filter-group[data-toggle= toggleID ]').toggle();
```

Change it to:

```
$('.filter-group[data-toggle=' + toggleID + ']').toggle();
```

```js
$(".filter-group").hide();

$('button').click(function() {

    var toggleID = $(this).data('toggle');
    $('.filter-group[data-toggle=' + toggleID + ']').toggle();

});
```

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-size:1.3rem;
}

button {
    padding:1rem;
    background-color:salmon;
    border:none;
}

.filter-group {
    background-color:silver;
    padding:1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" data-toggle="toggle1">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="toggle2">Button 2</button>


<div class="filter-group" data-toggle="toggle1">
    Filter Group 1
</div>

<div class="filter-group" data-toggle="toggle2">
    Filter Group 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this way.Define class name as per button attr

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="toggle1">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="toggle2">Button 2</button>

<div class="filter-group toggle1" data-toggle="toggle1">
  Filter Group 1
</div>

<div class="filter-group toggle2" data-toggle="toggle2">
 Filter Group 2
</div>
```

Change your js this way.

```
$(".filter-group").hide();
$('button').click(function() {
var toggleID = $(this).attr('data-toggle');
 $("."+toggleID).toggle();
});
```

Comment: thanks, i want to avoid classes in this place. there will be a lot of classes for stiles in this case. so i think it's clearer with data attribute.